# PHP: Pass another object as an argument to a function within the same class?

Tags: php, class, object

PHP: Can I pass another object as an argument to a function within the same class? What I need is a function that compares "this" object with another object of the same class. Something like:

```
class User {
  ...
  public $reputation;
  ...
  public function compareWithAnotherUser($user2) {
    if ($this->reputation < $user2->reputation) // do something
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried? It would have been quicker to try it yourself than to post the question here!

Comment: Sure, you can. Type-hinting will help you

Comment: Trying is ok, but I'm afraid to get into a situation where something unsupported accidentally works in my specific test.

Comment: Given that there are core PHP classes that do exactly this type of thing, I don't think its likely to become unsupported anytime soon

Comment: Example `DateTime::diff()`